# Using directlua command inside tikzpicture (pgf-pie) causes image not to render

Tags: latex

Using `\directlua` command inside tikzpicture (pgf-pie) causes image not to render:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % works
\pie[radius=2, rotate=100, sum=auto]
{
    3/test , 2/two , 3/three , 4/four
} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % does not work
\pie[radius=2, rotate=100, sum=auto]
 { 
    \directlua{tex.sprint("3/test , 2/two , 3/three , 4/four")} 
 } 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result can be view [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQWOy.png)

How gets `\directlua` expanded? And what do I need to change to create tikzpicture pie charts with variables from lua?